# Display dynamic product information on product Detail Page

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We are trying to build custom stock levels based on the Warehouse, a user selected. Until the user does not have a selected Warehouse, the stock level should be 0.

Now we are experiencing weird behaviour, where it still shows a Stock Level of 0, even though the user has selected a store with valid stock level for that product.

After some researching, we found several places in the java code, where calls like e.g. `getProduct` are being cached for 120 seconds or more. I guess this is done due to performance improvements..?

This cache control and max age for these calls even seems to persist over fresh incognito windows in e.g. google chrome.. Sometimes the `getProduct` call  is not even executed (Not listed in the network tab) and only get's executed after several hard refresh reloads (but still gives back the cached and therefore wrong response).
Sometimes it seems, that the cache persists for even longer than this 120 seconds, we haven't figured out yet, why..

This page explains how the caching can be implemented, but it does not say, how the server side caching works: https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/1905/en-US/8b711228866910149500b73575cb386e.html

[image]

My Questions around it:

1. How does the Server side caching work, how can it be invalidated (besides turning off the whole feature)
2. How should dynamic Product information be handled? Should the whole cache be disabled or rather a custom OCC endpoint be used to get the stock level?

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time we partially figured out, how we guess it works:

1. Server side Caching is done via EHCache, the time to live is defined in ehcache.xml
2. we needed to enhance the cache for productCode to also contain the selected store

Besides "fixing" the server side caching, we still have the problem, the the data is getting cached in the browser (we assume via Etag header, which is based on the response body). As the response body does not know anything about the selected store (sent via http header), it doesn't change, and therefore the data is not requested again after selecting the store..

Any idea on how include the information from the http header into the Etag value?

Comment: In the meantime we turned of client side caching for the product call completely, that makes it working, but obviously is not the goal and just an ugly workaround..